# Macbook pro 2019 Mac OS Catalina crackling sound issues

Tags: macos, mac, audio, macbook

I've been having crackling sound issues through my in built speaker on my Retina Macbook pro 2019 (MacBookPro16,1) model, I'm on MacOS Catalina.

I've had the issue for months, recent updates haven't helped.

However the cracking noise doesn’t happen all the time.

I can be watching a Youtube video in Firefox and I'll pause and come back in a few minutes and the cracking will start. If I then try the same video in Chrome it occurs there too.

I've also noticed this in slack too.

Therefore I don't think the issue is app specific.

If I switch the output from my built in speaker to a monitor, the sound is fine from the monitor, then when I switch back to the in built speaker, the crackling returns...

**Restarting my machine always fixes the problem.**

I found this guide..
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/special-effects-in-swiftui-blurs-blending-and-more

I've tried `sudo killall coreaudiod` which didn't help.

I believe I also tried `reset your PRAM/NVRAM` a few months ago, but I think the restart may have fixed the issue, temporarily.

I'm just wondering if anyone has any ideas for a permanent solution?

I'm not overly keen on reinstalling my machine and I can't really get to an Apple Store due to lockdown restrictions.

Comment: have the same problem. it doesn't happen with bluetooth connections, wired and speakers only.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a common problem with 2019 Macbook Pros. A workaround that may well work is to open Quicktime then select `file` > `new audio recording` and then minimize it. You don't actually need it recording. This workaround should stop the crackling until Apple finally fixes it (if ever).

Comment: Thanks, I'm awarding you the bounty, but the crackling hasn't happened again, will mark as the correct answer when it happens and I've tried it 